# How to improve response speed in a website, where a picture is drawn in real time at backend, using python-django

Tags: python, django, draw

I hope to improve response speed as much as possible, and I test the time my drawing function, which spends 2.9~3.2 seconds.
Any tips to improve the speed are appreciated, from algorithm, program,  website design...

The during time between 'user click draw button' and 'show picture in browser' is too long, using python and django, how can I reduce the time? Thanks in advance.

```
load 1.999396
angle2plane 3.0000000000196536e-05
getPoint 7.000000000090267e-06
getGrid 0.003222000000000058
D2MapD3 0.584085
getValue 0.032258999999999816
show 0.35327399999999987
total 2.982803

beg=time.clock()
ds=loadArray(filepath, (110,110,187))
end=time.clock()

print("load", str(end-beg))

ds=np.clip(ds, 0, 1)

print("alpha, beta, gamma:", alpha, beta, gamma)

beg=time.clock()
plane=angle2plane(alpha, beta, gamma, dis)
end=time.clock()
print("angle2plane", str(end-beg))

beg=time.clock()
A, B, C=getPoint(plane)
end=time.clock()
print("getPoint", str(end-beg))

beg=time.clock()
grid=getGrid(width, height)
end=time.clock()
print("getGrid", str(end-beg))

rowgrid=len(grid)
colgrid=len(grid[0])

beg=time.clock()
mpmatrix=D2MapD3(A, B, C, grid)
end=time.clock()

beg=time.clock()
values=getValue(mpmatrix, ds, width, height)
end=time.clock()
print("getValue", str(end-beg))

values=values.reshape(rowgrid, colgrid)

beg=time.clock()
plt.imshow(values)
plt.savefig("test.png")
end=time.clock()
print("show", str(end-beg))
```

Comment: apart from D2MapD3, the other long functions are loading and saving. What do you use to load and save (what storage?)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a long running task,
 you can try,
   **Using Celery with WebSockets** 
   You can initiate a celery worker ([refer here](https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/)) to do the long running job and return the 
   results via websocket ([django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))